# Add-on APK module using resources from the main app APK

Tags: android

I have an app, eg. `com.app`. I also have an optional module `com.app.module.m1`.
The optional module uses a lot of the resources already present in the main app mainly strings and drawables.

The module on its own is pointless and will not run (it is only a collection of components that can only be launched by the main app). There are no launcher icons and all entry points require `signature` level permissions.

If possible, I'd rather not duplicate these resources and just use the ones from the main app.

Can I somehow access the resources defined in `com.app` from `com.app.module.m1`?

Answer (score 0):

Use those methods:
`public Resources getResourcesForApplication(String pkgName);` in `PackageManager`
`public int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage);` in `Resources`.

For example,  if you want get a string resource named "app_name" in package "com.app".

```
try{
    Resources res = pm.getResourcesForApplication("com.app");
    int resId = res.getIdentifier("app_name", "string", "com.app");
    if(resId > 0)
        String mainAppName = getResources().getText(resId);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What about the XML? I was expecting to use @com.app:string/string_id, but it gets highlighted as error.